Simple Random Num Gen flutter-dart
I am trying to create random numbers after clicking the button. it works in the console but not on the UI. Need help with this. I am missing something
    import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RandomNum extends StatefulWidget {
  const RandomNum({super.key});

  @override
  State<RandomNum> createState() => _RandomNumState();
}

Random random = Random();
int randomNumber = random.nextInt(10);

class _RandomNumState extends State<RandomNum> {
  void randomNumberFunction() {
    setState(() {
      Random random = Random();
      int randomNumber = random.nextInt(10);
      print(randomNumber);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text(randomNumber.toString()),
          ElevatedButton(onPressed: randomNumberFunction, child: Text('Guess'))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


You are recreating new variable, remove the int
 void randomNumberFunction() {
    setState(() {
      Random random = Random();
      randomNumber = random.nextInt(10);
      print(randomNumber);
    });
  }

also you can use initState to set initial number instead of global and use the same random instance to generate number inside the function rest of the time.

Additionally OP should not be creating a new RNG each time.  There's already a global Random instance; just keep requesting random numbers from that.

You have globally initialize the variables and then again in your setState method, remove those and define it within the class.
Here's your updated code:
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RandomNum extends StatefulWidget {
  const RandomNum({super.key});

  @override
  State<RandomNum> createState() => _RandomNumState();
}

class _RandomNumState extends State<RandomNum> {
  Random random = Random();
  int randomNumber = 0;

  void randomNumberFunction() {
    setState(() {
      randomNumber = random.nextInt(10);
      print(randomNumber);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text('$randomNumber'),
          ElevatedButton(onPressed: randomNumberFunction, child: Text('Guess'))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


Thank you but i wanted it to start with a random number not with 0. this is how i solved it now.             ```dart
Random random = Random();
int randomNumber = random.nextInt(10);
class _RandomNumState extends State {
void randomNumberFunction() {
setState(() {
Random random = Random();
randomNumber = random.nextInt(10);
});
}

